# Applying existence and uniqueness of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

At page no. $333$ of Spivak's *Differential Geometry* book , theorem $13$ says that  fundamental existence and uniqueness theorem guarantees the existence of $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2 >0$ so that for $q \in U$ and $v \in M_q$ with $||v|| \leq \epsilon_1$  there exist a unique geodesic $\gamma_v\colon (-2 \epsilon_2, 2 \epsilon_2 ) \rightarrow M$ with required initial condition. I am not not getting how to apply the theorem to draw that conclusion.

My approach is first define a map $F\colon TM \rightarrow TM$ so that we can use the theorem to prove the solution of its velocity vector of geodesic. This way I have been able to prove that $\epsilon_1$ exists.

Comment: Just type $ around formulas ;)

Comment: Thanks michael for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

This theorem only tells us that under what conditions we have a solution of the problem and either solution will be unique or not. This not give us a technique or method to actually solve the problem.

Comment: but once you assume the christoffel symbols involved are $$ C^{\infty} $$ then locally lipshitz is automatically follows . Some how you need to formulate the problem to appeal to that theorem ...which I am not getting ..